# JqueryUI dialog doesn't work with specific input name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a strange difficulty with JqueryUI Dialog. This code doesn't work where input name is "submit". It works with all other input name (ex : submit2). Is someone know why and how to solve this problem because I can't change input name for different cause ? There is something wrong in Jquery script and I don't find what.

```
<form action="?" method="get" class="alert2">
    <input name="test" type="text" value="dataaaa" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="RECORD" />
</form>


$(function () {
    var confirmdialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>').appendTo('body');
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        bgiframe: true,
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Confirm'
    });
    $('form.alert2 input[type=submit]').click(function (theINPUT) {
        theINPUT.preventDefault();
        var theFORM = $(theINPUT.target).closest("form");
        $('#dialog').html('<P>confirm ?</P>');
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
            "Confirm": function () {
                theFORM.submit();
            },
                "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: What part of the dialog doesn't work? Seem fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/82x9j3qs/

Answer (score 0):

Click event works on elements of button type. When the element type is kept as "submit" the click events will fail to produce expected output.

Can you try following ?

```
  <form action="?" method="get" class="alert2"> 
       <input name="test" type="text" value="dataaaa" /> 
       <input name="submit" type="button" value="RECORD" /> 
   </form>

$(function(){
        var confirmdialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>').appendTo('body');
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    bgiframe: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Confirm'
    });

$('form.alert2 input[type=button]').click(function(theINPUT){
    theINPUT.preventDefault();
    var theFORM = $(theINPUT.target).closest("form");
    $('#dialog').html('<P>confirm ?</P>');
    $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
            "Confirm" : function() {
                theFORM.submit();
                },
            "Cancel" : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            });
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work.
I need to keep this code 

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="RECORD" />

Comment: do you have firebug installed - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/firebug/ ? If there are any errors, it will show you errors in Console > Errors section. Can you check it and update your question with the error that you are getting ? As  j08691 user commented, your code is working on jsfiddle. jsfiddle.net/j08691/82x9j3qs

Comment: The form is not submit. I don't understand why. No error in Firebug. If I change input button name, it works.

Comment: I found that : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10909 If someone have an issue (except change input name), it would be great